# Where to get the Datascience Use cases for practice

Tags: linear-regression, data-science-model, usecase

I just started  learning data science. I have gone through some of the courses in coursera & udemy, now i want to practice what i have learned. What i want to know is from where can i get the Use cases (linear regression & multiple linear regression) so that i could practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can start with the Kaggle datasets: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets
There are more then 22.000 datasets and they are very well documented, enough for hours and hours of practice.